# android bestway to keep temp data

Tags: android

hi in my application i have temp data , i need to keep the data only up to a particular condition , when app meet this condition,i don't need the data anymore. my problem how to keep the data,upon resuming the application

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing data in a sqlite database - there are lots of examples around the internet about how you can use sqlite database in an android application :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

or, you could store stuff in xml files

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

if you store data in xml or an sqlite database - the data is persistent until you specifically remove it.

Comment: MySQL? I think you mean SQLite!

Answer (score 0):

Using [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is the best way

Comment: depends on what temp data he's storing.  Shared preferences are good for names and what not, but what if he wants to store massive ammounts of data, such as 500 user names, weather for the next 6 months... etc?  SQLite would be much better for that